# What is the difference between NS() and ns() (Rshiny)

Tags: r, shiny, namespaces, shinymodules

NS() vs ns()
When to use the upper Case variant and when to use the lower case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

In this piece of code ns is assigned to NS(id)
now i can use ns("Name")

```
  mod_Navigation_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidPage(
      actionButton(ns("test"), "action"),
    )
   )}
```

If i delete the `ns <- NS(id)` I have to write:

```
mod_Navigation_ui <- function(id){
  tagList(
    fluidPage(
      actionButton(NS(id,"test"), "action"),
    )
  )}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is the `NS` function in the **shiny** package but there's no `ns` function.

It is common to do `ns <- NS(id)` in the UI part of a Shiny module, as shown in @Leo's answer (but you are not obliged to use the name `ns`). Then `ns` is a function: `ns("something")` returns the string `"moduleId-something"` if `id = "moduleId"`. As @Leo said, you can equivalently do `NS(id, "something")`. That is to say, `NS(id)("something")` is the same as `NS(id, "something")`.

```r
library(shiny)

id <- "moduleId"
ns <- NS(id)
ns("something")
# "moduleId-something"
NS(id, "something")
# "moduleId-something"
NS(id)("something")
# "moduleId-something"
unusual_name <- NS(id)
unusual_name("something")
# "moduleId-something"
```

In the server part of a Shiny module you have `session$ns` at your disposal. For a non-nested module, `session$ns` is the same as `NS(id)`. That is to say, `ns <- session$ns; ns("something")` is equivalent to `NS(id)("something")`. For a nested module, assuming the parent module is not nested, `ns <- session$ns; ns("something")` is the same as `NS(parentid)(NS(id)("something"))` where `parentid` is the module id of the parent module. So in the server part of a Shiny module it is better to use `session$ns` than `NS(id)` because `session$ns` will automatically handle the  situation where modules are nested.